Стоит ли призывать модератора на ответы сгенерированные ChatGPT?
Хочу задать вопрос непосредственно модераторам:
За последнее время мне попадались ответы, которые без сомнения выглядели как нейросгенерированные (даже без какой либо правки от отвечающего).
По совету старшего  товарища insolor  я взывал к силе модератора
Мои тревоги отметили как полезные, но на этом как бы и всё закончилось 
ChatGPT ответы как были опубликованы так и остались (кроме случая где снесли сам топик), нейроучастники и поныне здравствуют и всё такое..
В общем вопрос, а стоит ли вас модераторов тревожить на эту тему, если в этом какой-то практический смысл?

Лучше заменить заголовок на "Что делать с GPT-ответчиками?"

Что делать мне уже в прошлом вопросе сказали. Тут вопрос именно о целесообразности действия.

А логично, логично. Тогда лучше "Каковы действия модераторов по тревогам на ИИ-ответы?" А то заголовок "Требуется вмешательство модератора (тревога)" как-то очень хайпово  + указать ссылку на связанный вопрос

Название - небольшой кликбейт, но в целом строга по факту;))

А вот не надо кликбейта, в заголовке вопроса должна быть его суть

Никакого смысла в этом нет. Просто хорошие ответы надо плюсовать а плохие минусовать. Независимо от авторства. Вот и весь сказ.

@avp, не соглашусь с вами: Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?. Цитата оттуда: "Если вы увидите содержимое, опубликованное другими участниками, которое, вероятно, сгенерировано, сообщите об этом модераторам с помощью сигнала тревоги."

@Amgarak, прочтите мой комментарий выше — ставить тревогу стоит, об этом говорит правило сайта. А вот вопрос, интересующий, наверное, нас более: "Будет ли модерация что-либо делать с GPT-ответчиками?"

@Chaos_Sower вот в том и вопрос. Что вроде как ставить тревогу нужно, но если от этого толку 0, то смысла напрягать модеров лишней тревогой нет (им и так есть чем заняться).

@Chaos_Sower, зачем соглашаться со всем опубликованным на Мете? Думайте своей головой

@avp, это не опубликованное на Мете, а прямое правило сайта, которое должно исполняться (gpt-policy)

@Amgarak, "Толку 0"? А вот это явно не моя проблема. Это вопросы к модерации, почему они не исполняют прямое указание. Если оно не рабочее, тогда его надо удалять, а то двойные стандарты какие-то))

По-хорошему пунктик по поводу GPT-ответов надо регламентировать, а то комментарии оставляют как редакторы, так и прохожие (по типу "Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?"), а вот какую тревогу кидать на такое — непонятно... Нет такого пункта среди функционала тревог))

@Chaos_Sower, а вот последствие исполнения таких правил

@avp, я бы с вами подискуссировал, но я уже ложусь спать (не шучу). Вы связываете 2 неверные проблематики. Да, отток есть, потому что не все теперь задают вопросы, ведь есть GPT. Но как это связано с GPT-ответами? Такие ответы нужно банить без разговоров. Если пользователей-"пустышек" (надеюсь не резко сказал), повторяющих ответ за GPT станет меньше, то я думаю, что SO от этого только выигрыет

@Chaos_Sower, неужели трудно понять, что есть хорошие (правильные, толковые, полезные для многих программистов) ответы и есть плохие. И абсолютно не важно кто именно опубликовал (и откуда он взял этот текст) хороший ответ. Если же вы не уверены, что можете правильно оценить хорош ответ или плох, то просто пройдите мимо

@avp плохая идея: gpt будет учиться на своем же выхлопе, и результат будет все хуже и хуже. В нашем случае - это приведет к замусориванию базы знаний ответами сомнительного качества. Для этого и введено правило, чтобы такого саообучения не было. И это правило никак не может вызывать отток участников, не понятно что за логика у вас такая, что вы связали эти события.

@avp, сгенерированных ответов все еще довольно мало (к счастью), запрет на такие ответы никак не мог привести к оттоку.

@insolor, логика предельно очевидна. Больше запретов -- меньше свободы. Меньше свободы -- меньше желания делиться знаниями с людьми, которых устраивает такая ситуация

@avp, вообще не очевидно. Конкретно это правило касается настолько малого количества ответов, что на общую картину никак не влияет.

@insolor, кому как. Насчет свободы, это я больше про общую атмосферу на ruSO (ответы gpt это частность, но укладывается в общую картину)

@Amgarak, какую категорию тревог вы выбирали для таких ответов?

@Chaos_Sower так как ответа от модераторов не последовало, то просто ставлю флаг на призыв модератора с пометкой ChatGPT 105% - когда прям очевидная и бесполезная копипаста.

Не получив ответа от модераторов, я решил не прекращать ставить тревоги на очевидную и бесполезную копипаста от нейросетей.
Итоги:

Таким образом, если вы видите очевидно сгенерированные нейросетью ответы - смело отмечайте их тревогой. Тревоги обрабатываются, ответы удаляются, баны выписываются.


Хочу уточнить, а это какая тревога? Которая "Требуется вмешательство модератора"?

Опять Nymos? Я его тревогал ещё больше года назад...

@Byb да, именно она. Где можно самому что-то написать.

Понял, спасибо. Тогда теперь тоже буду её использовать
